# PyCharm failed when trying to read a big .csv file while spyder succeeded

Tags: pandas, pycharm, spyder

I have both pycharm and spyder installed on our remote desktop. I personally prefer pycharm and having been developing using it.
Everything is fine until I found that I can not read a .csv file which is bigger than 1 GB in pycharm, it told me python crashed and the log shows "Process finished with exit code -1073740940 (0xC0000374)".
At first I thought maybe the .csv file has been broken. But in spyder, the pandas succeeded reading it. So the .csv file is good.
I do not know why, I did not change the configuration of my PyCharm, maybe someone did, because there are several other colleagues who also have access to this remote desktop.

I am somewhat sure that the file is OK and I had been reading .csv files which are even bigger than 20GB in pycharm using pandas, so anybody have any idea about this?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the

```
idea.max.content.load.filesize=20000
```

line in the ide.[properties](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544869-Configuring-JVM-options-and-platform-properties). It controls the

> Maximum file size (kilobytes) IDE is able to open.

Answer (score 0):

This should open a 30mb file.

You can get to your properties file from Help > Edit Custom Properties.

```
idea.max.intellisense.filesize=30000
idea.max.content.load.filesize=30000
```

You may need to increase the total memory allotment in pycharm after you do this.  I know for me, pycharm slowed to a crawl while trying to read in a file this big.

More details on these settings: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/file-idea-properties.html